# Проблема с cookie в WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Не могу понять, как получать cookie от сервера через WebRequest. Просто не устанавливает и не видит их... Через браузер всё нормально, отображается установленная cookie server_id.

```
string url = "http://site.ru/test.php";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(result);
```

На самом сайте (на странице test.php):

```
setCookie('server_id', 123, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, '/');

echo $_COOKIE['server_id'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CookieContainer* - это коллекция, в которую можно добавить необходимые объекты типа Cookie. Вы ее просто инициализируете, не добавляя ничего в нее.

То есть для того, что бы отправить Cookie, надо сделать что то вроде:

```
var container = new CookieContainer();
container.Add(new Cookie("Name_1", "Value"));
container.Add(new Cookie("Name_2", "Value"));
```

А уж затем эту коллекцию можно и задавать запросу.

По поводу получить...
У вас есть ответ от сервера, то есть `HttpWebResponse response` - у ответа есть та самая коллекция с Cookie. Просто возьмите нужный, как из обычной коллекции, либо пройдитесь циклом.

Вот пример от [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) (для понятности того, какие значения можно вытянуть):

```
foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", cook.Domain);
    Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", cook.Path);
    Console.WriteLine("Port: {0}", cook.Port);
    Console.WriteLine("Secure: {0}", cook.Secure);

    Console.WriteLine("When issued: {0}", cook.TimeStamp);
    Console.WriteLine("Expires: {0} (expired? {1})",
        cook.Expires, cook.Expired);
    Console.WriteLine("Don't save: {0}", cook.Discard);
    Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", cook.Comment);
    Console.WriteLine("Uri for comments: {0}", cook.CommentUri);
    Console.WriteLine("Version: RFC {0}", cook.Version == 1 ? "2109" : "2965");

    // Show the string representation of the cookie.
    Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", cook.ToString());
}
```